# Can TypeScript decorators transform code when transpiling?

Tags: typescript, transpiler

I've started evaluating TypeScript again, coming from BabelJS.  I want to create class decorators to add certain behaviors or features to my code.  I've had some luck, but TypeScript seems to do this a little different than Babel.   Instead of adding the code to the transpiled results, it creates more complex decorator functions that essentially do it at runtime.  To me, this seems a little inefficient.  Possibly adding unnecessary executions at runtime and surely bloat when transpiling lots of files.  Anyhow, I'm wondering if I can control this transformation a little better, to make things more concise.   For example:

Input:

```
@managed
class MyClass {
   constructor() {
   }
}
```

Output:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
  function MyClass() {
    this.cid = 'MyClass';
  }
  return MyClass;
}());
```

Notice that in my desired output, it doesn't include the __decorate or code for the "managed" decorator.  It's just the final, desired ES5 code with no runtime extension.

Comment: No, you probably can't have that. But if this is what you're after, just have a base class for that and simply inherit it.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably eventually just use "extends".  Just learning the ropes.  So far, much of what I see coming out of decorators is a bit bloated.  I was hoping that they'd actually control the transformation.   From what I've seen so far, it makes more sense to code these things myself in a concise way.

Comment: I'm not sure how the compiler can do what it is you're asking it to do. Decorators are useful for certain use cases, and they are not the answer for others

Comment: Out of curiosity, where do you see Babel doing things at compile-time? Decorators are a runtime feature.